# JAXB unmarshalling from StringReader to xml with namespace

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I have a client response in the form of `ByteArrayInputStream` that I am buffered reading and creating a StringReader to read the xml in my pojo form. I want to unmarshal it but I am getting the namespace issue and hence JAXBException.

Here is my code after getting the response:

```
public void post() {
        ...

        ByteArrayInputStream obj = (ByteArrayInputStream) response.getEntity();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(obj));
        String line = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try{
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FileTransmissionResponse.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(sb.toString());
        FileTransmissionResponse transmissionResponse = (FileTransmissionResponse) 
        unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

}
```

The `StringBuffer` response is the xml in string format below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fileTransmissionResponse xmlns="http://abc.xyz.com/schema/auditing/fileResponse-1.1">
   <version>1.0</version>
   <userId>xqas</userId>
   <reNumber>1234</reNumber>
   <reName>1234rfd</reName>
   <status>FAILURE</status>
   <fileName>file.xml</fileName>
   <startTime>2021-04-06T09:16:54.065+10:00</startTime>
   <finishTime>2021-04-06T09:16:54.743+10:00</finishTime>
   <bytesTransferred>15530</bytesTransferred>
   <emailSent>scd@xyz.com</emailSent>
   ....
</fileTransmissionResponse>
```

The POJO class

```
package com.example.response;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "fileTransmissionResponse")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "version", "userId", "reNumber", "reName", "status", "fileName", "startTime", "finishTime", "bytesTransferred", "totalRead", "totalTransferred", "totalIntercepted", "emailSent", "message"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class FileTransmissionResponse {

    private String version;
    private String userId;
    private List<String> reNumber;
    private List<String> reName;
    private int status;
    private List<String> fileName;
    private String startTime;
    private String finishTime;
    private List<Integer> bytesTransferred;
    private List<Integer> totalRead;
    private List<Integer> totalTransferred;
    private List<Integer> totalIntercepted;
    private List<String> austracReference;
    private List<String> emailSent;
    private List<ErrorMessage> message;

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "version")
    public void setVersion(final String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "userId")
    public void setUserId(final String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public List<String> getReNumber() {
        return reNumber;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "reNumber")
    public void setReNumber(final List<String> reNumber) {
        this.reNumber = reNumber;
    }

    public List<String> getReName() {
        return reName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "reName")
    public void setReName(final List<String> reName) {
        this.reName = reName;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    public void setStatus(final int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<String> getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "fileName")
    public void setFileName(final List<String> fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "startTime")
    public void setStartTime(final String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getFinishTime() {
        return finishTime;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "finishTime")
    public void setFinishTime(final String finishTime) {
        this.finishTime = finishTime;
    }

    public List<Integer> getBytesTransferred() {
        return bytesTransferred;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "bytesTransferred")
    public void setBytesTransferred(final List<Integer> bytesTransferred) {
        this.bytesTransferred = bytesTransferred;
    }

    public List<Integer> getTotalRead() {
        return totalRead;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "totalRead")
    public void setTotalRead(final List<Integer> totalRead) {
        this.totalRead = totalRead;
    }

    public List<Integer> getTotalTransferred() {
        return totalTransferred;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "totalTransferred")
    public void setTotalTransferred(final List<Integer> totalTransferred) {
        this.totalTransferred = totalTransferred;
    }

    public List<Integer> getTotalIntercepted() {
        return totalIntercepted;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "totalIntercepted")
    public void setTotalIntercepted(final List<Integer> totalIntercepted) {
        this.totalIntercepted = totalIntercepted;
    }

    public List<String> getEmailSent() {
        return emailSent;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "emailSent")
    public void setEmailSent(final List<String> emailSent) {
        this.emailSent = emailSent;
    }

    public List<ErrorMessage> getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "message")
    public void setMessage(final List<ErrorMessage> message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

After unmarshal call, I get a JAXB Exception due to xmlns namespace. What are the ways to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `package-info.java` file to your package with `FileTransmissionResponse.java` class and define xml schema.

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://abc.xyz.com/schema/auditing/fileResponse-1.1",
elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.example.response;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there an alternative to this by any chance ?

Comment: There is also an option to define namespace parameter for `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement`, but I think this is the most convenient way of doing this.